# using 2-d arrays within functions and word count in C

Tags: c, function, word-count

I am new to C and have been learning in my spare time. I am struggling to grasp Functions so any help on those would be great but also to get my word count to work.

My program is to count the number of appearances of all words in the file and also produce a word count. I have thrown my best shot at it and have it working when displaying the occurrences all within the main function but when using my own functions they don't work.

My word count doesn't work either for some reason that I can't quite seem to figure out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Kindest regards,
John

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void print_occur_word(int initialarray[1000][10], int finalarray[1000][10], words);

void count_words(initialarray[1000][10])

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "rb");//opens sentences file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *str = malloc(fsize + 1);//uses malloc to  find size
    fread(str, fsize, 1, file);
    fclose(file);//closes

    str[fsize] = 0;
    int count = 0, c = 0, i, j = 0, appearance, space = 0, temp, temp1;
    char initialarray[1000][10], finalarray[1000][10];
    char *ptr;

    for (i = 0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == ' ')||(str[i] == ',')||(str[i] == '.'))
        {
            space++;
        }
    }


    for (i = 0, j = 0, appearance = 0;j < strlen(str);j++)
    {
        if ((str[j] == ' ')||(str[j] == 44)||(str[j] == 46))
        {
            initialarray[i][appearance] = '\0';
            i++;
            appearance = 0;
        }
        else
            initialarray[i][appearance++] = str[j];
    }

    appearance = 0;
    for (i = 0;i <= space;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j <= space;j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                strcpy(finalarray[appearance], initialarray[i]);
                appearance++;
                count++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcasecmp(finalarray[j], initialarray[i]) != 0)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    count_words(initialarray);
    print_occur_word(initialarray, finalarray, words);

    return 0;

}

int count_words(int initialarray[1000][10])
{
    int i,words=0;

    if(strlen(initialarray)==1)//if there are no words
        printf("Number of words in array:=%d",words);

    else
    {

        for(i=0;initialarray[i]!='\0';i++)//loop for finding words
        {
            //checking for blank space,new line and tab
            if((initialarray[i]==32)||initialarray[i]=='\t'||initialarray[i]=='\n')
                words++;//incrementing count of words
        }

        if(initialarray[i]=='\0')
            words++;
        return words;

    }
}

void print_occur_word(int initialarray[1000][10], int finalarray[1000][10], words)
{
    Printf("Number of words are: %d\n", words);
    int i, count, space, j, c;
    for (i = 0;i < count;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j <= space;j++)
        {
            if (strcasecmp(finalarray[i], initialarray[j]) == 0)
                c++;
        }
        printf("%s : %d \n", finalarray[i], c);
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `','` instead of 44 and `'.'` instead of 46, makes the code more readable.

Comment: What you really need to learn are *strings*, *arrays* and *POINTERS*. Because it's clear that you have no idea. It's one of the subtle parts of c that make [tag:c] a little bit hard to learn. Once you learn it, it becomes very simple. For the mean time, enable compiler warnings  because `strlen(initialarray)` is not going to work well. Also your logic here `if(strlen(initialarray)==1)` is quite hard to follow.

Comment: I don't pretend to be offensive, just honest and direct.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi not taken that way at all. I will go back and re-learn those over the next week. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Pablo will do. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy problem to solve, because you have to split the content,
store the words, count them, etc. There are many steps involved.

First, a few things I noticed:

```
if ((str[j] == ' ')||(str[j] == 44)||(str[j] == 46))
```

using the ASCII values is **not** incorrect, but it makes reading the code
harder, for us reviewing your code, and for your later. Use the characters
instead:

```
if ((str[j] == ' ')||(str[j] == ',')||(str[j] == '.'))
```

this is much easier to read. Also you are not taking into account when for
example multiple delimiters appear one after the other:
`"these are my thoughts.... I'd like to say"`. You are counting to many "spaces"
and adding to many empty strings to `initialarray`.

When you declare things like this:

```
char initialarray[1000][10];
```

you are limiting yourself to maximal 1000 words with maximal length of 9. That's
OK, but you will have to check that you don't write beyond the bounds. You are
not doing any bound checks, if you have more than 1000 words, you will overflow
the buffer, if the word is longer than 9 characters, you are overflowing the
buffer.

I'd write it like this: First define a structure that contains words and the
number of appearances. Create an array of the struct for every word and when you
add a new word, you have to check if the word is already there. If it is, then
add one to the counter, otherwise add the new word and set its count to 1. For example:

```
typedef struct word_count {
    char *word;
    size_t count;
} word_count;


int add_word(word_count **wc, size_t *len, const char *word)
{
    if(wc == NULL || word == NULL || len == NULL)
        return 0;

    // empty list
    if(*wc == NULL)
        *len = 0;

    // search for word
    for(size_t i = 0; i < *len; ++i)
    {
        if(strcasecmp((*wc)[i].word, word) == 0)
        {
            (*wc)[i].count++;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    word_count *nwc = realloc(*wc, (*len + 1) * sizeof *nwc);
    if(nwc == NULL)
        return 0;

    // creating copy of word
    nwc[*len].word = strdup(word);
    if(nwc->word == NULL)
        return 0; // do not update *len

    nwc[*len].count = 1;
    *wc = nwc;
    (*len)++;
    return 1;
}

void free_words(word_count *wc, size_t len)
{
    if(wc == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        free(wc[i].word);
    free(wc);
}
```

With `add_word` I store the words and count them at the same time. First I go
through the array and check if the word is already stored in the array. In that
case I only increase the count number. If this is a new word, then I reallocate
memory for one more word and add the word and set the count to 1.

Now you can do:

```
void foo(void)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    word_count *wc = NULL;

    add_word(&wc, &len, "word1");
    add_word(&wc, &len, "word2");
    add_word(&wc, &len, "word3");
    add_word(&wc, &len, "word2");
    add_word(&wc, &len, "wORD1");

    if(wc)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            printf("word: '%s', count: %zu\n", wc[i].word, wc[i].count);
    }

    free_words(wc, len);
}
```

and you would get:

```
word: 'word1', count: 2
word: 'word2', count: 2
word: 'word3', count: 1
```

Then the function that counts the word uses `strtok` to get the word. `strtok`
modifies the source string, so in order to preserve the original content, I make
a copy and use `strtok` on that.

```
word_count *get_word_counts(const char *file, size_t *len)
{
    if(file == NULL || len == NULL)
        return NULL;

    word_count *wc = NULL;
    *len = 0;

    // I do a copy because strtok modifies the source
    // preserving the original content
    char *copy = strdup(file);
    if(copy == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    const char *delim = " \t,.\r\n!"; // \n to consume newlines as well

    char *token = strtok(copy, delim);

    do {
        // if empty word
        if(token[0] == 0)
            continue;

        if(add_word(&wc, len, token) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to add word '%s'\n", token);
            free(copy);
            return wc; // returning all words so far
        }

    } while((token = strtok(NULL, delim)));

    free(copy);

    return wc;
}
```

I put these functions together and created a text file with your question as
content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct word_count {
    char *word;
    size_t count;
} word_count;

int add_word(word_count **wc, size_t *len, const char *word)
{
    if(wc == NULL || word == NULL || len == NULL)
        return 0;

    // empty list, create one
    if(*wc == NULL)
        *len = 0;

    // search for word
    for(size_t i = 0; i < *len; ++i)
    {
        if(strcasecmp((*wc)[i].word, word) == 0)
        {
            (*wc)[i].count++;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    word_count *nwc = realloc(*wc, (*len + 1) * sizeof *nwc);
    if(nwc == NULL)
        return 0;

    nwc[*len].word = strdup(word);
    if(nwc->word == NULL)
        return 0; // do not update *len

    nwc[*len].count = 1;
    *wc = nwc;
    (*len)++;
    return 1;
}

void free_words(word_count *wc, size_t len)
{
    if(wc == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        free(wc[i].word);
    free(wc);
}


long get_file_size(const char *filename)
{
    if(filename == NULL)
        return -1;

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if(fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not seek to the end: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        fclose(file);
        return -1;
    }

    long fsize = ftell(file);

    fclose(file);

    return fsize;
}

char *get_file(const char *filename, long *filesize)
{
    if(filename == NULL)
        return NULL;

    long fs = get_file_size(filename);
    if(fs == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not calculate file size\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(filesize)
        *filesize = fs;

    // I use calloc so that the buffer is \0-terminated
    char *res = calloc(1, fs + 1);
    if(res == NULL)
        return NULL;


    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        free(res);
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(fread(res, 1, fs, fp) != fs)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get the whole file\n");
        free(res);
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return res;
}

word_count *get_word_counts(const char *file, size_t *len)
{
    if(file == NULL || len == NULL)
        return NULL;

    word_count *wc = NULL;
    *len = 0;

    // I do a copy because strtok modifies the source
    // preserving the original content
    char *copy = strdup(file);
    if(copy == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    const char *delim = " \t,.\r\n!"; // \n to consume newlines as well

    char *token = strtok(copy, delim);

    do {
        // if empty word
        if(token[0] == 0)
            continue;

        if(add_word(&wc, len, token) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to add word '%s'\n", token);
            free(copy);
            return wc; // returning all words so far
        }

    } while((token = strtok(NULL, delim)));

    free(copy);

    return wc;
}


int cmp_count(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
    word_count *w1 = (word_count*) s1, *w2 = (word_count*) s2;
    return strcasecmp(w1->word, w2->word);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int ret = 0;
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    long fs = 0;
    char *file = get_file(argv[1], &fs);
    if(file == NULL)
        return 1;

    size_t len = 0;
    word_count *wc = get_word_counts(file, &len);

    if(wc == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to count words\n");
        ret = 1;
        len = 0;
    }

    // sorting words
    if(wc)
        qsort(wc, len, sizeof *wc, cmp_count);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("word: '%s', count: %zu\n", wc[i].word, wc[i].count);

    free_words(wc, len);
    free(file);
    return ret;
}
```

The output is:

```
word: 'a', count: 1
word: 'all', count: 2
word: 'also', count: 2
word: 'am', count: 2
word: 'and', count: 3
word: 'any', count: 2
word: 'appearances', count: 1
word: 'appreciated', count: 1
word: 'at', count: 1
word: 'be', count: 2
word: 'been', count: 1
word: 'best', count: 1
word: 'but', count: 2
word: 'C', count: 1
word: 'can't', count: 1
word: 'count', count: 4
...
```

Note that I use `strdup` to create the copies of the words and the file content. If your system does
not have `strdup`, you can use this:

```
char *strdup(const char *text)
{
    if(text == NULL)
        return;

    char *copy = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    if(copy == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return strcpy(copy, text);
}
```

---

**edit**

> *OP asked in the comment section*
>
> how would I go about sorting the file by having the biggest number of occurrences first?

All you need to do is change the function `cmp_count` or create a new one with a
different comparison. `qsort` passes a pointer
to the values that need to be compared and you have to return 0 if the values
are equal, less than 0 if the left value is smaller and greater than 0 if the
left value is larger. In case of descending sort, you have to swap the sign,
meaning that you return something less than 0 if the left value is greater, and
something more than 0 if the left value is smaller.

So, if you want to sort by number of occurrences, you have to check `w1->count`
with `w2->count`.

```
int cmp_count_by_count_desc(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
    word_count *w1 = (word_count*) s1, *w2 = (word_count*) s2;
    return w2->count - w1->count;
}
```

then you have to change the `qsort` line in `main` to:

```
if(wc)
    qsort(wc, len, sizeof *wc, cmp_count_by_count_desc);
```

Running the same test input with the new sort, I get

```
word: 'to', count: 6
word: 'my', count: 6
word: 'I', count: 4
word: 'count', count: 4
word: 'the', count: 4
word: 'and', count: 3
word: 'have', count: 3
word: 'word', count: 3
word: 'work', count: 3
word: 'am', count: 2
word: 'in', count: 2
word: 'Functions', count: 2
word: 'any', count: 2
word: 'help', count: 2
word: 'would', count: 2
word: 'be', count: 2
word: 'but', count: 2
word: 'also', count: 2
word: 'of', count: 2
word: 'all', count: 2
word: 'it', count: 2
word: 'when', count: 2
word: 'new', count: 1
word: 'C', count: 1
word: 'been', count: 1
...
```

Comment: So by using a struct we are able to dynamically size it so we do not limit ourselves to a certain memory allocation?

Also I had a done some digging into Strtok just after I posted this question and found it the most beneficial way counting the occurrences with the skill set I have atm (not very much I know).

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, thanks to the `realloc` and `strdup` you file can have as many words of any length (as there is memory available, of course)

Comment: Hi again, how would I go about sorting the file by having the biggest number of occurrences first? thanks, John

Comment: @JohnSmith I've made an update of my answer with addressing your question.

Comment: @JohnSmith I saw you deleted the next question. The `add_word` function does not care where, when and how the strings was fetched. So you've only got to change the `main` function. Instead of using `char *file = get_file(argv[1], &fs);`, you can do: `char line[1024]; fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);` and call `word_count *wc = get_word_counts(file, &len);`. The rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into it a little more and reminded myself and was able to get it working! Thanks for again for all your help!

Comment: I have attempted to use your code above instead of mine. To run my program I use ./program -i filename.txt 

I continue to get undeclared identifiers after the 'char line[1024]' line. Any help?

Comment: @JohnSmith in the `else` section where you use `fgets`, the next line where you call  `get_word_counts`, you are passing `file` and not `line`!

Comment: Hi Pablo, that never solved the issue of undeclared identifiers from 

word_count *wc = get_word_counts(line, &len); 

&len being the undeclared identifier and every other identifier onwards such as wc and ret. 

I was thinking something to do with my if statement at the beginning of the main function?

Or where I pass the values to get_word_counts?

Kindest regards,
John

Comment: @JohnSmith post on pastebin 1:1 your code, and I'll take a look

Comment: @JohnSmith  https://pastebin.com/hxj11Um7 I made a correction at 132, read my comments there. Also read the comments I left in the `main` function. Main problem was that you declared many variables only in the `if`/`else` blocks but wanted to access them outside the `if`/`else` blocks, that an error. Read my comments on the file. The code I posted on pastebin works, I compiled it and tested it. I also left more comments after the `main` function, read them.

Comment: @JohnSmith I only tested it with`-i filename`, I didn't test the code from stdin. There is an error there, in a couple of minutes I'll repost another pastbin with the fix

Comment: @JohnSmith here https://pastebin.com/nqhbzKkA is the corrected version for when no arguments are passed in the command line.

Comment: Thanks again Pablo, I was hoping to had add a overall word count. I haven't worked with structs a lot before so not if we can add the count struct together?


I did attempt it this way but https://pastebin.com/vM2WUnYb but it only counts the words once.



Also how would I go about writing this struct to a file if the command line argument is declared as ./program -i filename.txt -o filename.txt and if it isn't then it just does what it does just and print out to the terminal.

Obviously I will need to use the argv[3] statement but I have never written to file from a struct.

Comment: @JohnSmith this is getting out of hand, the comment section is not for long discussions. Your `number_of_words` variable has the same value as `*len`. I also advice you to create a new question if you have further questions. Like I said, the comment section is not the place to have large discussions.